# HttpAntiForgeryException occurs with multiple Login tabs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm trying to handle *HttpAntiForgeryException*.

The issue is as follows:

1. A user opens several tabs with Login page (i.e. by mistake)
2. Signs in on one of the tabs
3. Opens another tab and forgets that he has already been logged in on the previous tab  and pushes "Log in" button

Then we are getting the following exception:

*The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current user is "username".*

I seem to be unable to debug the controller's *Login* action. I have breakpoints set and they are getting fired only if you post the form for the first time on one of the tabs, however if you are then pushing "Log in" button on any other tab - the breakpoints aren't getting fired. I have no idea how to handle this.

Is there a way to handle this using javascript on Login page ?
Are there any other ways of handling this in the controller or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
public class HandleAntiForgeryError : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    #region IExceptionFilter Members

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var exception = filterContext.Exception as HttpAntiForgeryException;
        if (exception != null)
        {
            var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
            routeValues["controller"] = "Account";
            routeValues["action"] = "Login";
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

And then put *[HandleAntiForgeryError]* before Login method in the AccountController.